# Запрет завершения приложения

Tags: android, qt

Как запретить завершать приложение, при нажатии кнопки `Назад` в `Qt` на `Android`? Просто, у меня приложение подключается к серверу, и мне необходимо, чтобы приложение не завершалось сразу же.

Comment: Всегда стройте приложение исходя из того, что оно может быть в любой момент "прибито" системой. Такова сама природа Андроид ОС.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо породить сервис из приложения. Вот перевод из [официальной документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidservices.html):

> Начиная с Qt 5.7 появилась возможность создавать Android-сервисы с использованием Qt. Сервис — это компонент, работающий в фоне и не имеющих пользовательского интерфейса. Он нужен для выполнения длительных операций, например журналирования данных GPS или ожидания оповещений от социальных сетей. Сервис продолжает работу даже после того, как запустившее его приложение было закрыто.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете запретить приложению "завершиться". Максимум - это прехватить кнопку Back и проигнорировать нажатие. Но кнопка Home не переопределяется и не перехватывается.

Если у вас обращение к серверу должно продолжаться, его необходимо реализовывать не в Activity, а в Service. Service, в отличие от Activity, при переходе к другому приложению не будет выгружен из памяти и продолжит работу.